# The Remove Duplicate Messages add on to Mozilla Thunderbird does not find all duplicates

Tags: email, thunderbird, deduplication, thunderbird-addon

I have upgraded my email hosting and copied bulk messages from folders in the old server to the same folder in the new server. However in some cases I have copied many messages multiple times so have duplicates in the folders. Using the 'remove duplicates' menu item from the [Remove Duplicate Messages](https://addons.thunderbird.net/En-us/thunderbird/addon/removedupes/?src=ss) add-on finds only 2 messages in a folder, when I know there are around 1300.

Why?

Comment: Have you read the FAQ: https://github.com/eyalroz/removedupes/wiki/FAQ-(Frequently-Asked-Questions).

Comment: I hadn't to be fair, wasn't aware that it existed nor that the add-on had any configurable settings. Is working well now!

Comment: @Robert, answer provided as requested!

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out the duplicates add-on has configuration settings available from:

```
Tools > Add-on options > Remove Duplicate Messages
```

From here the different characteristics are choosable for comparison. In my case the two servers stored the messages differently, altering the format of the sender and recipient addresses, the email header information, number of lines, and the total message size. I was able to retain

- Message ID
- Send time
- Subject and
- Folder

and have the search behave accurately.

[image]